# what is equivalent of stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth (iOS) for Android?

Tags: android, ios, button, imageview, stretch

is there any method, property or xml tag for Android to stretch image like iOS?

for example:

```
UIImage *stretchableBackButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6];
[button setBackgroundImage:stretchableBackButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it stretches the image from 6 px to whole width/height.

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found it.
it is Nine patch. there is no method or any xml tag. image file must be redrawn by draw9patch tool.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

You can do this code in xml imageView

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

or you can use through program like this

```
imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: it just stretches the image. my back image is 11x11 png with rounded corners. 5px round + 1px line + 5px round (from left to right and same thing for up to down).  when i use stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6, it stretches the just 6.px, then it aligns the 5 rounded right corner/bottomcorner to the right side/ bottom side.